# How to create a class which restricts methods based on the input file? Creating a database API

Tags: python, oop, methods

This question is more about how one uses OOP to read in databases. SQLite and sqlite3 are simply examples to work with, and are not the main thrust of the question. (Arguably Python is only used here to explain my point):

I am creating a software package which allows users to query SQLite index files which have already been generated. It's basically syntactic to make it super user-friendly to query SQLite files indexed in a certain way, for a very particular case This should be quite straightforward, but I am somewhat confused how to "automatically" read in the SQLite

Here's an example (with pseudo-code):

```
import sqlite3

Class EasySQL:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath

    def connect(self, filepath):  ## perhaps this should be above in init?
        return sqlite3.connect(self.filepath)

    def query_indexA(self):
        ## query index A on SQLite3 connection

    def query_indexB(self):
        ## query index B on SQLite3 connection

    def query_indexC(self):
        ## query index C on SQLite3 connection

    def query_indexD(self):
        ## query index D on SQLite3 connection
```

Here's my problem: users would have access to only two types of indexed SQLite files. The "Type 1" files are only indexed on A and B---indices C and D do not exist in this SQLite files, and should throw an error if users try to call these functions. The "Type 2" files are only indexed on C and D---indices A and B do not exist in this SQLite files, and should throw an error if users try to call these functions.

How do I "restrict" these methods such that if a user calls (for example) `query_indexC` on a "Type 1" SQLite file, there's an error?

I would strongly prefer not to force users to use two separate classes, as that is far too complicated, e.g. `EasySQL_Type1()` or `EasySQL_Type2()` A flag for which type would be ok though.

Comment: How do you determine what's a "Type 1" and what's a "Type 2" file?

Comment: @zwer The user must upon entering the file. Or, in the example above, the "wrong" query found must somehow throw an error, i.e. "Error: there's no B index"

Comment: Yes, but your class needs to know which one is which if you want to throw errors based on type. That means that the user would need to inform your class of the type of the file passed and the question is - how do you imagine that process?

Comment: @zwer The users are the ones who generated either a sqlite file of "type1" or a sqlite file of "type2". So, if they remember, they would be the ones to set this. However, you're correct---there could be human error. It would probably be better to automatically "check" the index type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can properly discern the type of file you can easily store that as internal reference and throw errors when trying to access 'invalid' indexes. You can also establish the connection to your SQLite file in the `__init__()` as, short of network drives, you won't need reconnection handling.

There are, of course, edge cases, but this should get you started:

```
import sqlite3

class EasySQL(object):

    def __init__(self, filepath, index_type=1):  # type 1 by default
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(filepath)
        self.index_type = index_type

    def query_indexA(self):
        if self.index_type != 1:
            raise ValueError("indexA can only be queried by index type 1")
        # do your indexA processing... your DB is available in self.connection

    def query_indexB(self):
        if self.index_type != 1:
            raise ValueError("indexB can only be queried by index type 1")
        # do your indexB processing... your DB is available in self.connection

    def query_indexC(self):
        if self.index_type != 2:
            raise ValueError("indexC can only be queried by index type 2")
        # do your indexC processing... your DB is available in self.connection

    def query_indexD(self):
        if self.index_type != 2:
            raise ValueError("indexD can only be queried by index type 2")
        # do your indexD processing... your DB is available in self.connection
```

Now your users can initiate it with:

```
type1_db = EasySQL("path/to/their/file.sqlite", 1)  # for type 1, or
type2_db = EasySQL("path/to/their/file.sqlite", 2)  # for type 2
```

And if they attempt to use methods not associated with their types it will raise a `ValueError`. If you don't want to leave to the users to provide the type of their database file, you'll have to devise a way to determine it from the file itself (name, schema, whatever).

Comment: This makes sense to me. Question to help me learn: Let's say we can some hypothetical function `check_index()` which would check the file "type" at instantiation---given that such a function exists, how would that be implemented above?

Comment: @EB2127 - you can always create such function and call it immediately after connecting to the SQLite DB. Say that it returns the actual type, you can call it as: `self.index_type = self.check_index()` or something along those lines. You then don't need to rely on users to provide you with the index.